# Topology active subgroup for the QCD vacuum

Tags: quantum-field-theory, group-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, topology, topological-field-theory

I've been reading about the nontrivial topological structure of the QCD vacuum and, when studying the different equivalence classes created by the pure gauge fields, all papers say that it is possible to work with $SU(2)$ instead of $SU(3)$, since this subgroup is the only "topologically active" part in the discussion. They cite a theorem by Raoul Bott from a paper called *[An Application of Morse theory to the topology of Lie groups](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/An-application-of-the-Morse-theory-to-the-topology-Bott/6ec08cd6d31be98664280fa3c7425690229d3772)*.

Since I come from a physics background, I don't understand that paper or why we can restrict the discussion to only $SU(2)$. Are there any good resources that explain this particular case or the mathematical background necessary to understand it?